# Caliburn Micro MVVM: Handling data exchange from one View/ViewModel to other ones

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I created a wpf project (using caliburn micro with MVVM pattern, no code-behind) with 2 view models and their related views:

- ShellView.xaml and ShellViewModel.cs
- OtherView.xaml and OtherViewModel.cs

The ShellView contains:

- ContentControl which refers to OtherView/OtherViewModel.
- A TextBox, which contains so called "target text".

The OtherView contains a StackPanel which contains:

- A TextBox which accepts text from user (as "source text").
- A Button which copies the source text to target on Right-MouseButton Click event.

**My questions:**

- How to copy the source text which is in OtherView/ViewModel to target text which is in ShellView/ViewModel? Any best practice for it?
- Can ShellViewModel catch the PropertyChange event from source TextBox?
- How to copy in opposite direction (from target to source)?

Thank you in advance and please feel free to modify the code below if needed.

**ShellView.xaml**

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="CmMultipleViewModelView.Views.ShellView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    d:DesignHeight="450"
    d:DesignWidth="800"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid Width="800" Height="450">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ContentControl
            x:Name="ActiveItem"
            Grid.Column="0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center" />

        <TextBox
            x:Name="TargetText"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Width="80"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**ShellViewModel.cs**

```
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<object>
{
    public ShellViewModel()
    {
        DisplayName = "Shell Window";
        var otherVM = new OtherViewModel();
        ActivateItem(otherVM);
    }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    private string _targetText = "Target";
    public string TargetText
    {
        get => _targetText;
        set
        {
            _targetText = value; 
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => TargetText);
        }
    }
}
```

**OtherView.xaml**

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="CmMultipleViewModelView.Views.OtherView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    d:DesignHeight="150"
    d:DesignWidth="150"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <StackPanel
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBox
            x:Name="SourceText"
            Width="80"
            Margin="3" />
        <Button
            x:Name="CopyText"
            Width="100"
            Margin="3"
            Content="Copy" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

**OtherViewModel.cs**

```
public class OtherViewModel : Screen
{
    private string _sourceText = "Source";
    public string SourceText
    {
        get => _sourceText;
        set
        {
            _sourceText = value; 
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SourceText);
        }
    }

    public void CopyText()
    {
        // How to copy the SourceText to TargetText using Caliburn Micro MVVM?
        // Can ShellViewModel catch the PropertyChange event from source textbox?
    }
}
```

**Edited:**

**AppBootstrapper.cs**

```
public class AppBootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
{
    private readonly SimpleContainer _container = new SimpleContainer();

    public AppBootstrapper()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    public ShellViewModel ShellViewModel { get; set; }

    protected override object GetInstance(Type serviceType, string key)
    {
        return _container.GetInstance(serviceType, key);
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type serviceType)
    {
        return _container.GetAllInstances(serviceType);
    }

    protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
    {
        _container.BuildUp(instance);
    }

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        base.Configure();
        _container.Singleton<IWindowManager, WindowManager>();
        _container.Singleton<IEventAggregator, EventAggregator>();
        _container.Singleton<ShellViewModel>();
        _container.PerRequest<OtherViewModel>(); // Or Singleton if there'll only ever be one

    }

    protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            base.OnStartup(sender, e);
            DisplayRootViewFor<ShellViewModel>();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

**ShellViewModel.cs**

```
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<object>, IHandle<string>
{
    private readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

    public ShellViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAgg, OtherViewModel otherVm)
    {
        _eventAggregator = eventAgg;
        _eventAggregator.Subscribe(this);
        ActivateItem(otherVm);
    }

    public sealed override void ActivateItem(object item)
    {
        base.ActivateItem(item);
    }

    public OtherViewModel OtherViewModel { get; set; }

    private string _targetText = "Target";
    public string TargetText
    {
        get => _targetText;
        set
        {
            _targetText = value; 
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => TargetText);
        }
    }

    public void Handle(string message)
    {
        TargetText = message;
    }
}
```

**OtherViewModel.cs**

```
public class OtherViewModel : Screen
{
    private readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

    public OtherViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAgg)
    {
        _eventAggregator = eventAgg;
    }

    private string _sourceText = "Source";
    public string SourceText
    {
        get => _sourceText;
        set
        {
            _sourceText = value; 
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SourceText);
        }
    }

    public void CopyText()
    {
        _eventAggregator.PublishOnUIThreadAsync(SourceText);
    }
}
```

**Edited again**

added

```
_container.Singleton<IWindowManager, WindowManager>();
```

in AppBootstraper::Configure

Problem solved!

Comment: During setting of your `ActivateItem` you could set DataContext to some new property of `OtherViewModel` and then in your OtherView in `CopyButton` you could make Command, with CommadParameter binded to `newPropertyWithDataContextOfShellView.TargetText`

Comment: Or just use some kind of Messenger

Comment: [Event Aggregator?](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/event-aggregator)

Comment: Event Aggregator and a custom event is the right solution. This reduces coupling between your views and allows you to completely replace the ShellViewModel or OtherViewModel functionality without changing the other one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have said, the correct way is to use the event aggregator.

If you're using the SimpleContainer in Caliburn.Micro then in your OnConfigure override you'd put:

```
_container.Singleton<IEventAggregator>();
```

This will create an instance of an IEventAggregator when you first access it. Now, you have a choice of how you access it. Either by injecting into your constructor or using the IoC.GetInstance method.

If you want to inject then you'll need to modify your viewmodels:

```
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<object>, IHandle<string>
{
    private readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

    public ShellViewModel(IEventAggregator eventagg, OtherViewModel otherVM)
    {
        _eventAggregator = eventagg;
        _eventAggregator.Subscribe(this);
        ActivateItem(otherVM);
    }

    public void Handle(string message)
    {
        TargetText = message;
    }
}

public class OtherViewModel : Screen
{
    private readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

    public OtherViewModel(IEventAggregator eventagg)
    {
        _eventAggregator = eventagg;
    }

    public void CopyText()
    {
        _eventAggregator.PublishOnUIThread(SourceText);
    }
}
```

In the Bootstrapper you'll then need to register both your viewmodels:

```
_container.Singleton<ShellViewModel>();
_container.PerRequest<OtherViewModel>(); // Or Singleton if there'll only ever be one
```

So, what's all this doing?

In your ShellViewModel we're telling it to implement the IHandle interface for strings.

```
IHandle<string>
```

Anytime a string event is fired the ShellViewModel will call the Handle method with the same signature. If you only want to handle specific types then create a new class to hold your copy text and change the handler from string to your type.

```
IHandle<string>

IHandle<yourtype>
```

When the event aggregator receives the string event it will call any listeners Handle method. In your case Handle(string message). If you change the IHandle type you'll also need to change the Handle method to the same type.

```
public void Handle(string message)
{
    TargetText = message;
}
```

This will set the TargetText to whatever the string value is that you fired in your event.

We have an instance of IEventAggregator, this is a singleton object so anywhere it's referenced it should be the same one. We've modified your ShellViewModel constructor to accept an IEventAggregator object and an instance of your OtherViewModel.

Once we've stored the reference to the event aggregator locally we call:

```
_eventAggregator.Subscribe(this);
```

This tells the event aggregator that we're interested in any events that will be handled by the IHandle's we've defined on the class (you can have multiple as long as they handle different types).

With the OtherViewModel it's a little different, we've again added IEventAggregator to the constructor so we can inject it on start up but this time we're not subscribing to any events as OtherViewModel only fires an event.

In your CopyText method you would call:

```
_eventAggregator.PublishOnUIThread(SourceText);
```

This raises the event on the event aggregator. Which is then propagated to the ShellViewModel which handles it with the Handle method.

As long as you register your view models and the event aggregator in the SimpleContainer instance in your Bootstrapper then Caliburn.Micro will know which items to inject into the constructors when it creates the instances of your VM's.

The flow would go:

ShellViewModel subscribes to the string event

_eventAggregator.Subscribe(this);

User types some text into SourceText
User presses right mouse button, this invokes:

```
CopyText()
```

Which calls:

```
_eventAggregator.PublishOnUIThread(SourceText);
```

The event aggregator then checks all the subscribed view models that have a IHandle interface and then calls:

```
Handle(string message)
```

on each one.

In your case this then sets the TargetText to the message:

```
TargetText = message;
```

Apologies for the wall of text!

There is a much simpler way which is to have your ShellViewModel subscribe to the PropertyChanged event on OtherViewModel:

```
otherVM.PropertyChange += OtherVMPropertyChanged;
```

Then in handler you'd have to look for notifications of the SourceText property and update your target text. A much simpler solution but would mean you'd tightly couple your ShellVM and OtherVM plus you'd have to make sure to unsubscribe from the event when you close the OtherVM otherwise it will never get garbage collected.

## Here's how to set up the DI container

In your Bootstrapper class you''ll want to add the SimpleContainer:

```
private SimpleContainer _simplecontainer = new SimpleContainer();
```

Then you'll need to override some methods and make sure the code is as below:

```
protected override object GetInstance(Type serviceType, string key)
{
    return _container.GetInstance(serviceType, key);
}

protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type serviceType)
{
    return _container.GetAllInstances(serviceType);
}

protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
{
    _container.BuildUp(instance);
}
```

Now override the OnConfigure method. This is where we tell Caliburn.Micro what ViewModels we're using and where we set up the EventAggregator and the WindowManager (so it can wrap your ShellViewModel in a window):

```
protected override void Configure()
{
    base.Configure();

    _container.Singleton<IWindowManager, WindowManager>();
    _container.Singleton<IEventAggregator, EventAggregator>();

    _container.Singleton<ShellViewModel>();
    _container.PerRequest<OtherViewModel>(); // If you'll only ever have one OtherViewModel then you can set this as a Singleton instead of PerRequest
}
```

Your DI is all now set up.
Finally in your StartUp override you'll just make sure you've got it looking like this:

```
protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(sender, e);

    DisplayRootViewFor<ShellViewModel>();
}
```

If you run your application now, when the ShellViewModel is created Caliburn.Micro will look at the constructor parameters of ShellViewModel to see what it needs to provide. It will see that it requires an event aggregator and OtherViewModel so it will look in the SimpleContainer to see if they've been registered. If they have then it will create the instances (if needed) and inject them into the constructor. As it creates the OtherViewModel it will also check the constructor params and also create whatever that needs.

Finally it will display the ShellViewModel.

Comment: I will try your suggestion and be back a bit later.

Comment: where should I put **new ShellViewModel( newEventAgg, newOtherVm)** (the ShellViewModel's constructor call using DI) ?

Comment: I am stuck at: (1) where to call **the ShellViewModel's modified constructor** and **the OtherViewModel's modified constructor** using Dependency Injection and (2) **where to create EventAggregator for first time**

Comment: This would be done in the Bootstrapper. I suggest looking here [Caliburn.Micro simple IoC container](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/simple-container). I'll update the answer with some more info.

Comment: I've updated the answer. See the "Here's how to set up the DI container" section.

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you very much! :-)

Comment: I get System.NullReferenceException. Debugger executes following calls: AppBootstrapper -> Configure -> OnStartup -> GetInstance (twice) -> Constructor OtherVM -> Constructor ShellViewModel -> ActivateItem -> System.NullReferenceException. Am I still missing something?

Comment: You'd need to give me a little more information on what your bootstrapper looks like. I assume you've overridden the methods I listed; GetInstance, GetAllInstances and BuildUp and in each one you used the correct name for your SimpleContainer instance? Your SimpleContainer instance is instantiated? private SimpleContainer _container = new SimpleContainer(); in the mian body of your Bootstrapper?

Comment: I just edited my question above and put the current viewmodels and bootstraper there.

Comment: It looks mostly ok. Not sure why you've got public ShellViewModel ShellViewModel { get; set; } in your Bootstrapper. or why you've got public OtherViewModel OtherViewModel {get;set;} in your ShellViewModel. If you're attempting to access either of these properties you'll get NullRefs. You could try changing the PerRequest<OtherViewModel> to Singleton<OtherViewModel> and see if that makes the issue go away. Other than that I'll need to re-create your application in VS to see if I can reproduce it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176727/discussion-between-magb-and-handbagcrab).

Comment: No need. I've solved it! I left out one vital step in the Configure override. Funny thing is I left it out as I didn't want to have to explain it! You need to add _container.Singleton<IWindowManager, WindowManager>(); before the event aggregator singleton line in your Bootstrapper. After that your application will work fine! I'm so stupid not to have noticed. If CM doesn't have a window manager then it can't wrap your ShellViewModel in a window!

Comment: You're welcome. I'll edit my answer to include the IWindowManager.